# Генерация документации в doxygen

Tags: doxygen, php, ubuntu

Доброго времени суток.

Так сложилось, что мне никогда не приходилось использовать doxygen для генерации документации. Сейчас появилась необходимость.

Вопрос. У меня есть папка с кодом: `/var/www/`,необходимо обработать код и сгенерить доку к нему. В коде комментарии написаны по стандарту, с этим проблем не возникнет.

Вопрос, как настроить doxygen для того, чтобы он обрабатывал именно эту папку и генерировал документацию  исходя их исходников ?

Если можно по шагам. Язык - PHP.

ОС- ubuntu. doxygen установлена. Использовать GUI для настройки не могу.
Если можно, опишите консольный вариант настройки.  Спасибо :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cd /var/www/
doxygen -g
doxygen
```

Comment: Появляются 2 папки:

1. Latex
2. Html

Что с ними делать дальше ? В папке html - тупо шаблон. открываю в браузере - вижу просто стартовую страницу, более ничего нету
В latex - ваще ничего не понятно :)

Поясните, пожалуйста, более подробно :)

Comment: Почитайте вот здесь http://courses.graphicon.ru/files/courses/cg/2008/prac/doxygen.pdf 
мне кажется он неможет распарсить коментарии

Comment: Все, спасибо. Покопался в настройках этого файла конфигурационного. Все стало на свои места :) Спасибо )